# Sort a List Using Comparable and Comparators in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

I am attempting to complete a lab project that requires me to read in data from a .txt file and sort it in various ways using both comparable and comparators. The list is of students and their grades on two tests, and needs to be sorted in various ways: in order of name, in order of first grade, in order of second grade, and in order of total grade, using both the .sort method and comparators. I think I've gotten most things done right, but every time I try to run the program, I get an error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "". I can't get it to print out at all to see if I've done all the rest of the code right. I'm not sure where to look to fix it; at first I thought it was in my initial declaration of the String array but if I take out that space (turning (" ") into ("")) I get the same error, but as: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e". I feel like I'm probably missing something totally easy and obvious, but it's got me stumped.

Here is my code. A separate Student class contains the getters and constructor, and can be posted if it is needed.

```
public class Program {

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    try {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
        String line=br.readLine();
        List<Student> s=new ArrayList<Student>();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            String array[]=line.split(" ");
            Student ob=new Student(array[0],Integer.parseInt(array[1]),Integer.parseInt(array[2]));
            s.add(ob);
            line=br.readLine();

        }

        System.out.println("Here is the data as initially read in:");
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %3d\n", s.get(i).getName(), s.get(i).getScore1(), s.get(i).getScore2());


        }
        System.out.println("**************");

        System.out.println("Data After Normal Sorting");
        Collections.sort(s);
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %3d\n", s.get(i).getName(), s.get(i).getScore1(), s.get(i).getScore2());


        }
        System.out.println("**************");
        System.out.println("Sorting on the basis of First Score");
        Comparator<Student> myComparator1 = (o1, o2) -> {
            int result = String.valueOf(o2.getScore1()).compareTo(String.valueOf(o1.getScore1()));
            return result;

        };
        Collections.sort(s, myComparator1);
        Collections.reverse(s);
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %3d\n", s.get(i).getName(), s.get(i).getScore1(), s.get(i).getScore2());


        }
        System.out.println("**************");

        Comparator<Student> myComparator2 = (o1, o2) -> {
            int result = String.valueOf(o2.getScore2()).compareTo(String.valueOf(o1.getScore2()));
            return result;

        };
        Collections.sort(s, myComparator2);
        Collections.reverse(s);
        System.out.println("Sorting on the basis of Second Score");

        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %3d\n", s.get(i).getName(), s.get(i).getScore1(), s.get(i).getScore2());


        }

        System.out.println("**************");

        System.out.println("Sorting on the basis of Total Sum of Score");

        Comparator<Student> myComparator3 = (o1, o2) -> {
            int result = String.valueOf(o2.getScore1()+o2.getScore2()).compareTo(String.valueOf(o1.getScore1()+o1.getScore2()));
            return result;

        };
        Collections.sort(s, myComparator3);
        Collections.reverse(s);
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %3d\n", s.get(i).getName(), s.get(i).getScore1(), s.get(i).getScore2());


        }


        System.out.println("**************");




    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

For reference, the text in the grades.txt file is as follows:

```
Deirdre     70  62
Florence    37  90
Chris       60  68
Aaron       53  80
Elmer       91  40
Betty       79  50
```

If anybody can spot what is going on, and explain to me where the error is coming from and what is causing it so that I can see where I've gone wrong, I would be very appreciative!

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` expects numbers in the strings, otherwise it'll throw an error. You should check that you are splitting the string correctly

Comment: YUP it was something obvious and silly! Gosh I hate when I do that, I was just having a total brain blank. Thank you so much, it is working as intended now and I feel dumb.